# How can I fix the coordinate-type change that occurs from dragging in d3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Right now in my program I have both a drag function and a zoom function.

The problem can best be illustrated in this [minimal test case.](https://jsfiddle.net/gamea12/g7n3rk40/1/) When the zoom is initiated at first, you may notice that the points in the graph will transition just fine. But, if you drag a point before initiating a zoom, that point will usually travel outside the scope of the graph.

This problem seems to be happening because my coordinates are defined in scaled space centered around the upper left corner. However, after an object is dragged, its coordinates are switched to pixel space, centered around its original coordinates. When a zoom occurs, it will then treat the pixel coordinates as scaled space coordinates relative to the upper left corner, which causes problems.

I would appreciate any tips or pointers and thanks in advance

Drag function:

```
function dragmove(d) {

    var barz = document.querySelector("#visual");

    var point = d3.mouse(barz),
        tempP = {
            x: point[0],
            y: point[1]
        };

    if (this.nodeName === "circle") {

        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();

        var useZoom = $('#zoom').is(":checked");
        if (useZoom == false) {


            d.usePixels = 1;
            d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = tempP.x - xRange(d.initx)) + "," + (d.y = tempP.y - yRange(d.inity)) + ")");

            //events to update line to fit dots
            updateXs();
            redoLine();

            updateBars(canvas);
        }
    }     }
```

Zoom function:

```
 function zoomOut() {
    //update axis
    yRange.domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
        return d.y - 10;
    }), d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
        return d.y + 10;
    })])

    yAxisGroup.transition().call(yAxis);

    xAxisGroup.transition().attr("transform", "translate(0," + yRange(0) + ")");

    //update line
    d3.select(".myLine").transition()
        .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData));

    var c = vis.selectAll("circle")
    c.transition()
        .attr(circleAttrs)
}
```